# pygtk: how to switch window_state from popup_menu

Tags: python, menu, gtk, pygtk, tray

This is my code:

```
def configure_event(self, widget):
    if self.is_hiding:
        self.window.present()
    else:
        self.window.iconify()

def delete_event(self, widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()
    return True

def popup_menu(self):
    self.menu = gtk.Menu()
    self.about = gtk.MenuItem("about")
    if self.is_hiding:
        self.expand = gtk.MenuItem("show")
    else:
        self.expand = gtk.MenuItem("hide")

    self.quit = gtk.MenuItem("quit")

    self.about.connect("activate", self.about_monitor)
    self.expand.connect("activate", self.configure_event)
    self.quit.connect("activate", self.delete_event)

    self.menu.popup(None, None, gtk.status_icon_position_menu, event_button, event_time, self.tray_icon)

    self.menu.append(self.about)
    self.menu.append(self.expand)
    self.menu.append(self.monitor)
    self.menu.append(self.quit)

    self.menu.show_all()
```

`delete_event` works, but `configure_event` does not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

look at the signatures of both of them:

```
def configure_event(self, widget):
def delete_event(self, widget, data=None):
```

`delete_event` has a third argument `data` (that has a default of `None`) but `configure_event` only has two.

although i don't know what the exception was i bet that the exception was:

```
TypeError: configure_event() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

if so changing `configure_event`'s signature to:

```
def configure_event(self, widget, data):
```

would fix it. note that i think the default value of `None` is unneeded as gtk will pass something in always.